# How to decide which Probability distribution to use on a specific problem?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability, data-science, probability-theory

Which probability distribution i can use to understand the number of orders one person can handle in a company? It's like each person has orders which takes minimum of 50 days to complete and no limit is there on how many one can handle.So, i was thinking to check out a way to limit the number of orders one can handle which will not result into overburdening of resources. Can anyone help me how can i solve this? I thought of "poisson distribution" but i want some expert guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off topic as not a programming question. This belongs in something like the stats.stackexchange